# How to improve the Orbeon Form performance/execution

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have developed an Orbeon Form with 500 controls.
It has got many interdependent controls which leads to bunch of conditions in binding for required, readonly, calculate etc etc..

Now When i change something in a drop down, it takes more time to execute the binding conditions. But this drop down is binded for only 3 other controls on readonly/required/calculate/relevant.

I would understand whether the whole model bindings are executed every time when there is change in any control or only the dependent bindings are executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out `xxforms:refresh-items` [link](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-performance-settings#TOC-Controlling-item-sets-refreshes-wit).  What happens is these select and select1 options are computed on the xforms-refresh event.  If you know that these options will not be changing, the `xxforms:refresh-items` will create the options once in the beginning of the form and not try to update them again.

For more general performance tweaking: [link](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/performance-tuning)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the link to the wiki page on [performance tuning](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/performance-tuning) already mentioned by @Anthony, it looks like the situation you describe is exactly what the [XPath analysis](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-analysis) feature is designed to help with. Without analyzing XPath expressions, Orbeon Forms needs to reevaluates almost all your XPath expressions almost every time users interact with the form, and sometimes even multiple times per interaction.

Now, you should be aware that this is a PE-only feature, but if you are not already using Orbeon Forms PE, and that this feature makes a difference to how well your large form performs, getting the PE might be worth it for you.